# How do I make the theme dots reappear in jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have jsTree set up and it is working great with jSON. After changing my jSON structure the dots seemed to have stopped working. 
below is my code. I received the jSON code from here https://www.js-tutorials.com/jquery-tutorials/jstree-example-href-jstree-search-node-scrollbar/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jstree').jstree({

        plugins: ["themes","html_data", "state", "wholerow"],
        'core' : {
             'themes' : {
            'theme' : "apple",
            'dots' : true,
            'icons' : false
        },
            'data' : jsonTreeData
        }
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
         var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
         var parentId = data.node.a_attr.parent_id;
         if(href == '#')
         return '';

         window.open(href);

    });
    $('#jstree').slimScroll({
        height: '200px'
    });
     $('#jstree').showDots();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem your JSON data structure rather `wholerow` plugin. It's the default behaviour of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@asif is right, when the wholerow plugin is used, it continiusly send messages to hiode_dots. You can call show_dots whenever this happens, bnut the tree will looks awfull, as the selection color and hover color is overwriting some of the rows, instead of combine the 2. Long story short, you are better off by using either wholerow or dots/lines